# Cuda kernel producing the resultant vector as zero

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Here is the kernel that I am launching for calculating some array in parallel.

```
 __device__ bool mult(int colsize,int rowsize,int *Aj,int *Bi,int *val)
    {       
        for(int j = 0; j < rowsize;j++)
        {           
           for(int k = 0;k < colsize;k++)
            {   
              if(Aj[j] == Bi[k])
               {    
                return true;
                }                               
            }           
        }
            return false;       
    }


__global__ void kernel(int *Aptr,int *Aj,int *Bptr,int *Bi,int rows,int cols,int *Cjc)
    {
        int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        int i;
        if(tid < cols)
        {
            int beg = Bptr[tid];
            int end = Bptr[tid+1];
            for(i = 0;i < rows;i++)
            {
                int cbeg = Aptr[i];
                int cend = Aptr[i+1];
                if(mult(end - beg,cend - cbeg,Aj+cbeg,Bi+beg))
                {                                                
                     Cjc[tid+1] += 1;
                     //atomicAdd(Cjc+tid+1,1);           
                }
            }                
        }               
    }
```

And here is how I decide the configuration of grid and blocks

```
int numBlocks,numThreads;

        if(q % 32 == 0)
        {
            numBlocks = q/32;
            numThreads = 32;
        }
        else
        {
            numBlocks = (q+31)/32;
            numThreads = 32;
        }
findkernel<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(devAptr,devAcol,devBjc,devBir,m,q,d_Cjc);
```

I am using GTX 480 with CC 2.0. 
Now the problem that I am facing is that whenever `q` increases beyond `4096` the values in `Cjc` array are all produced as `0`.
I know maximum number of blocks that I can use in X direction is `65535` and each block can have at most `(1024,1024,64)` threads. Then why does this kernel calculate the wrong output for `Cjc` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I finally figured out using `cudaError_t` that when I tried to `cudaMemcpy`  the `d_Cjc` array from device to host, it throws following error.

```
CUDA error: the launch timed out and was terminated
```

It turns out that some of the calculations in `findkernel` are taking reasonably large amount of time which causes the display driver to terminate the program because of OS 'watchdog' time limit.

I believe I will have to shut down X server or ssh my gpu machine (from another machine) by removing its display.This will buy me some time to do the calculations that will not exceed the 'watchdog' limit of OS.

Comment: How big are your matrices? If they are not REALLY huge I'm pretty sure you can do this without shutting down X! First of all, 32 threads seems to be much too low - have you tried using 128 or 256? Another possibility woud be to rewrite your kernel: Currently, you iterate over all rows for each column. If `rows` is large, this is very inefficient. You could compute the result of `mult` per matrix entry (0 or 1) and then sum up the values per column using a parallel prefix sum (Thrust `scan`). _(There are probably more efficient methods, this was just what came to my mind immediately...)_

Comment: @kroneml...rows and cols are of order `4096`,`8192` and so on....Right now I am using `thrust::inclusive_scan` after all the calculations are over and `dCjc` is copied back to host side....

Answer (score 0):

I seems like there are a couple of things wrong with the code you posted:

1. I guess `findkernel` is `kernel` in the CUDA code above?
2. `kernel` has 8 parameters, but you only use 7 parameters to call `findkernel`. This doesn't look right!
3. In `kernel`, you test `if(tid < cols)` - I guess this should be `if(tid < count)`??
4. Why does `kernel` expect `count` to be a pointer? I think you don't pass in an `int` pointer but a regular integer value to `findkernel`.
5. Why does `__device__ bool mult` get `count`/`int *val` if it is not used?

I guess #3 or #4 could be the source of your problem, but you should look at the other things as well.

Comment: @kroneml....I have edited my code....I guess I posted my code from back up file which had older code in it...
1) Yes 
2) 3) 4) 5) I have edited my code..